# Cannot evaluate a namespace path to class as variables

Tags: php, class, object, path, namespaces

When I hardcode a namespace and class, a new object is instantiated. But any way I try to instantiate the namespace as a variable, the class "does not exist".
How do I get PHP to evaluate the entire path to the class dynamically?

```
class Export
{
  public function exportIt($appPath) // $appPath = 'theApp'
  {
    $appClass = 'thisClass';

    $appObj = new $appPath . '\\' . $appClass(); // <-- Says class does not exist :-(

    $appObj = new theApp\thisClass(); // <-- Instatiates OBJECT! :-)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which class does it say doesn't exist? My money is on `theApp`, and you're being bitten by the `new` operator having higher precedence than anything else in that statement.

Have you tried:

```
$appFullPath = $appPath . '\\' . $appClass;
$appObj = new $appFullPath();
```

Comment: I did try that, and many other ways, thanks Greg. It sounds like there's no way to make it work like this. It's operator precedence over a variable? Where it doesn't have precedence over a class object?

Comment: I tried something exactly like this, though obviously not with your particular class, and it worked fine. If it's not working for you, then there's some other problem. Perhaps `appPath` should start with a `\\`?